# How to remove AdPeak lqw.me script from my web pages?

Tags: javascript

A company called AdPeak, which seems less than reputable, owns the domain lqw.me, which has managed to attach a script file to every one of my web pages on any browser I choose to use. It looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="2f2a695a6afce2c2d833c706cd677a8e" src="http://d.lqw.me/xuiow/?g=750C2C5B-CF42-6996-0E5A-306165564128&s=F5D333A8-C748-4686-AE0A-9E008F670C22&z=1384886096"></script>
```

It appears immediately after the `<head>` tag on every page in every browser. It also makes some pages not fully load, breaking the page.

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: [Answer is found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20531150/1934286).

Comment: I wonder why there are two close votes here? Please explain why you are voting to close. I won't learn site guidelines unless you tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, AdPeak is one of those less than reputable companies that manages to install their extensions on your browsers when all you wanted to install was something else.

AdPeak is the owner of lqw.me and all its subdomains, too, according to the Whois.

Simply turning off and removing the extension is not enough. The script file will still appear in nearly every page you view. You will have to uninstall a program (which you likely did not intentionally install).

Go to Start Menu > Control Panel > Programs and Features

Find any program with the publisher listed as "AdPeak, Inc." or has "ScorpionSaver" in the name. Uninstall them and reboot your computer. This should make the problem stop completely.

Comment: May also be called Savingsbullfilter

Comment: I also want to note that Malwarebytes Antimalware will remove it as well during a full scan (you cannot get all of it with a quick scan).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is happening on S3 as I don't see it there. Perhaps its not your upload path but your download one that it borked. Check your extensions, local firewalls, etc for badware.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll get it same as you.
After seaching around. I download this https://www.malwarebytes.org/free/

Setup, Scan. It detect malwares
Chose quaranties all malware It found.
Re Thread scan.

Wait some minutes. It will remove all malwares include AdPeak too.