# Rails - Unrecognized syntax in my Development Logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, logging, syntax

I was viewing my development logs just now and was surprised to see unreadable characters.

```
I, [2014-12-27T20:12:04.511024 #24794]  INFO -- : Started GET "/orders/%EF%BF%BD
-u%02?o=3&g=&s=&z=%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD
/%D4%A9?" for 75.32.9.84 at 2014-12-27 20:12:04 +0000

I, [2014-12-27T20:12:04.521924 #24794] INFO -- : Processing by OrdersController#show
as */*

I, [2014-12-27T20:12:04.522138 #24794] INFO --: Paramaters: {"o"=>"3", "g"=>"",
"s"=>"", "z"=>"□□□□□□□□/\u0529?", "id"=>"□-u\u0002"}
```

I don't need to know how to fix this, but I need to diagnose it, so I understand what's wrong with it. I have never seen such syntax in my development logs before.

Does anyone have any idea what language this is or why it's here?

Thanks in advance

Edit

I researched some more on StackOverflow and now I'm worried. Could my website be infected by the `lqw.me` malware? I read the posts, and it sounds like that's what's happening.

Here's the link

[Weird characters in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222973/weird-characters-in-url)

There's always a "g", "s", and "z" parameter, and sometimes a "o" parameter that has values of 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%EF%BF%BD` decodes in UTF-8 as the [replacement character](http://codepoints.net/U+FFFD), which is usually put in when a sequence cannot be decoded. `%D4%A9`, if UTF-8, decodes to a [cyrillic supplementary character](http://codepoints.net/U+0529).

As to why it is there, it's because someone at `75.32.9.84` sent it in a GET request.