# URIError: Failed to decode param - Encode binary image Filepond

Tags: node.js, json, database, mongodb, filepond

I send an image as type:binary and parse into JSON to the DB where it is a json string. If I want to query the image it throws an error

> URIError: Failed to decode param '%EF%BF%BD...' at decodeURIComponent
>   ()

I save encode the image as follows:
Inside models folder:

```
...
paintings: { type: Buffer },
paintingsType:{ type: String }

    postSchema.virtual('paintingsP').get(function() {
        if (this.paintings != null && this.paintingsType != null) {
            return `data:${this.profilpicType};charset=utf-8;base64,${this.profilpic.toString('base64')}`
        }
    })
```

Inside the router.js

```
// **Inside a router.put function**
...
if (req.body.paintings != null && req.body.paintings !== '') {
            savePaintings(post, req.body.paintings)
        }

function savePaintings(post, profilpictureEncoded) {
     if (profilpictureEncoded == null) return;
     const profpic = JSON.parse(profilpictureEncoded);
     if (profpic != null && imageMimeTypes.includes(profpic.type)) { // If the file is a json obj & from the type image (jpg, png)
         post.paintings = new Buffer.from(profpic.data, 'base64')    // Buffer.from(where, how)
         post.paintingsType = profpic.type
     }
 }
await post.save();
```

If I look up everything seams good, so where could be the problem? Did my request is wrong?
Inside the DB: [image: DB]

I use express, mongoose, ejs and FilePond *(for saving the files)*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222973/weird-characters-in-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird characters in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222973/weird-characters-in-url)